# Merge [ADC] and [analog-digital-converter] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

- [adc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adc):

  > An analog-to-digital converter (ADC) is a device that converts a continuous signal to a serie of digital numbers.
- [analog-digital-converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/analog-digital-converter):

  > Anything related to analog-to-digital converters (ADCs). ADCs are hardware devices that convert analog signals to digital signals.

We have 286 questions with the tag [adc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adc) but only 76 questions with the tag [analog-digital-converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/analog-digital-converter). That's obvious because no one uses the term "analog-digital-converter" in real life. To an embedded engineer's perspective they're the same and should be merged together to [adc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adc) with `analog-digital-converter` being a synonym to it.

Possible incorrect usage:

- [Application delivery controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_delivery_controller)

  - All the questions in the [adc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adc) tag use the word *controller* in it [to mean *microcontroller*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Badc%5D+controller)
  - There's no question in the [adc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adc) tag with "delivery", "balance", "firewall" or "network" in it
  - There's a single question that use [ADC with this meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1486122/995714) and I've created a new tag for it
- A few Apple-related questions seem mistakenly use ADC as [Apple Developer Connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer) and I've corrected all of them

In case it's too easy to make a mistake the reverse direction is also OK IMHO, with a note in the excerp like the [dac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dac) tag:

> Questions utilizing the DAC tag are expected to relate to some aspect of Microsoft Data Tier Applications or DAC. Questions can include the DAC framework or DACfx, schema scripts from DACPAC, and combined data/schema scripts BACPAC. For questions about **digital-analog converters**, use [digital-analog-converter].

Comment: yes, because I learned electronics and worked with ADC. You can also see the phrase `analog-to-digital converter` in the [tag:adc] tag and `ADC` in the other tag wiki

Comment: @pnuts I just looked through the 50 most recent questions in the ADC tag and all are using it to mean analog-to-digital converter.

Comment: @pnuts I found only a question that uses ADC as *Application delivery controller*. There are more use it as *Apple Developer Connection* but I've fixed all of them. Please see my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree, I have posted a synonym request here:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/adc/synonyms

Users with 2500 rep or more, kindly vote.

Comment: I approved the synonym, in the same way as you had proposed.

Answer (score 13):

I agree. The tags should be combined and made synonyms.

In embedded systems, "ADC," if otherwise unqualified, pretty much always means "Analog-to-Digital Converter." (I'm an embedded systems engineer.)

I scanned through the most recent 50 questions in the ADC tag and all were using it to mean "analog-to-digital converter."